# On-shell propagator to an off-shell propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory, ward-identity

I am learning the Ward-Takahashi Identity part of Peskin and Schroeder's textbook of quantum field theory. In the prove process, it involves a diagram 7.66.

[image]

Then it says that

[image]

I can understand physically that as the process is a on shell propagator to a off-shelf propagator process,  which means it is a real particle to a virtual particle process and so does not contribute to the $S$-matrix (I hope I got that right). However, I wonder is there another explanation like from mathematical perspective to explain that the diagram on the RHS does not contribute to S matrix.